# Storage compatibility: Solidity upgradable smart contract using "proxy" design pattern and changing the mapping type

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Anyone used the "proxy" pattern to write [upgradable smart contracts](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/writing-upgradeable)?
I am planning to upgrade/extend my old smart contract, originally, my code looks like this:

```
mapping(address => uint256)  balance;
```

I am planning to write it like this:

```
struct PackedBalance {
    uint256 balance;
    uint256 locked_balance;    // to support a new feature.
}
mapping(address => PackedBalance) balance;
```

My concern is if the "storage" is compatible to the "old version smart contract".

I just read the "[Layout of State Variables in Storage](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/internals/layout_in_storage.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage)". As I understand it, it is compatible. But I am a newbie, so I would like  to seek help from some experts.

"compatible" means: I can still read correct "balance" of the existing storage slots. And I can write "locked_balance" without breaking anything(like overwritten).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's safe to expand the `uint256` within a mapping to the `struct` within the same mapping.

Lets debug these two example contracts:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    mapping(address => uint256) balance;
    
    function setBalanceForAddress(address _address, uint256 _balance) external {
        balance[_address] = _balance;
    }
}
```

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    struct PackedBalance {
        uint256 balance;
        uint256 locked_balance;
    }

    mapping(address => PackedBalance) balance;
    
    function setBalanceForAddress(address _address, uint256 _balance, uint256 _lockedBalance) external {
        balance[_address] = PackedBalance(_balance, _lockedBalance);
    }
}
```

The `address` is always going to be `0x1231231231231231231231231231231231231231` (for debugging purposes).

The first contract stores the `uint256` field to storage slot `0xf100689cc6bb188feb3c0ef4658bee6e8042e58e79daebcd84870d7f336a8422`

Tx data:

```
0x4fa1007300000000000000000000000012312312312312312312312312312312312312310000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064
```

Remix debugger screenshot:

[image: Remix debugger screenshot]

---

The second contract stores the `struct` to slots `0xf100689cc6bb188feb3c0ef4658bee6e8042e58e79daebcd84870d7f336a8422` (same as the first contract) and `0xf100689cc6bb188feb3c0ef4658bee6e8042e58e79daebcd84870d7f336a8423` (right next to it).

Tx data:

```
0x6f7223d9000000000000000000000000123123123123123123123123123123123123123100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000640000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064
```

Remix debugger screenshot:

[image: Remix debugger screenshot]

Comment: However， `hardhat` would give an error: "Error: New storage layout is incompatible".

Comment: @AndyJiang It's a check used by the [openzeppelin-upgrades](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-upgrades) package. I's not related to Hardhat or EVM in general.  Here's an open issue on their GitHub related to the error message - https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-upgrades/issues/73 ... Possible solutions: 1) Comment out the check in your local copy of the `openzeppelin-upgrades` package. 2) Perform the proxy upgrade without this package. 3) Wait for OpenZeppelin to allow the change in the package. 4) Submit a pull request that allows suppressing the error, ...